# Extracting Files from Firefox Tabs Using Webextensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions

As the title states I am attempting to extract files from a firefox tab using webextensions. Specifically PDF files or Image files. Currently I have the following basic ContentScript for web pages that works.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.action == "GetPageContent") {
      // get webpage url
      url = document.location.href;
      // get webpage content
      page_content = document.documentElement.outerHTML;

     // Send message to background script to process this page and its content.
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"url": url, "page_content": page_content});
    }   
  }
);
```

when I send a message from this content script to my background script it simply prints out all of the webpage HTML stored in page_content. How can I extract the binary information of images or PDF files as a string and pass it in a similar fashion to be printed to a console or a notification? One thing I noticed is that for PDF files currently I can get the full HTML of the PDF.js page that Firefox renders when opening PDF files. Which is fine for now, but in the case of images how do I fetch that raw image data as a string?

Comment: the page has an URL, simply fetch that url via XHR.